# Allocating Sold period to Units according to logic

Tags: excel, indexing, excel-formula

I am trying to allocate certain unit IDs to periods. For example, I have a table, that states that in period 1 5 units would be sold.

**Proposed Allocation**

```
Period  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10  
Units   5  1  0  3  2  4  0  0  0   1
```

I now want to allocate period 1 to the first 5 unit ids, period 2 to unit id 6, period 4 to ids 7 to 9, period  5 to unit 10 to 11, period 6 to unit ids 12 to 15, and period 10 to unit id 16.

**Outcome**

```
UnitID  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10  11  12  13  14  15  16  
Period  1  1  1  1  1  2  4  4  4   5   5   6   6   6   6   10
```

In the above, the first 5 units are allocated to period 1, in accordance with the first table.

Is this possible without using VBA?

Comment: Can you continue your example?  What's happening with the rest of the columns besides 1?  Also, does this represent how the data is actually laid out?  ie., 2 rows total?

Comment: Also, you sample was displaying & editing strangely -- something to do with your region's RTL (right-to-left) settings, I *think*... Anyhow I think I fixed it but please confirm that your data is still lined up as you intended.  (if not, you can Rollback my [revision](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49689755/revisions).)

Comment: Hi, thank you for helping to edit the sample data. I continued my example above, hopefully it makes more sense now.

Comment: See, it **did** make a difference!  By the time I got back here you had 2 answers now that it's more clear what you wanted to do.

Answer (score 1):

This is an array formula which can be used to give the required data if entered in B5 and pulled across

```
=IFERROR(IF(COLUMN()=2,1,IF(COUNTIF($A$5:A5,A5)<INDEX($B$2:$K$2,MATCH(A5,$B$1:$K$1,0)),A5,INDEX($B$1:$K$1,MATCH(1,($B$1:$K$1>A5)*($B$2:$K$2>0),0)))),"")
```

At the moment it assumes that the row headers start in column A and that the first number is 1, so could be made more general.

Must be entered with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

[image]

You can use this formula if you prefer not to have to use Ctrl-Shift-Enter

```
=IFERROR(IF(COLUMN()=2,1,IF(COUNTIF($A$5:A5,A5)<INDEX($B$2:$K$2,MATCH(A5,$B$1:$K$1,0)),A5,INDEX($B$1:$K$1,MATCH(1,INDEX(($B$1:$K$1>A5)*($B$2:$K$2>0),0),0)))),"")
```

And here is a more general version which starts off with the first period number which doesn't have zero units.

```
=IFERROR(IF(COLUMNS($A:A)=1,INDEX($B$1:$K$1,MATCH(TRUE,INDEX($B$2:$K$2>0,0),0)),IF(COUNTIF($A$5:A5,A5)<INDEX($B$2:$K$2,MATCH(A5,$B$1:$K$1,0)),A5,INDEX($B$1:$K$1,MATCH(1,INDEX(($B$1:$K$1>A5)*($B$2:$K$2>0),0),0)))),"")
```